# C++ multi-threading: thread-safe memory allocation

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand if in C++11 new/delete are thread-safe.
I have found conflicting answers.
I am running this short program and sometimes I get different results from the two threads (I would expect to always get the same result instead).
Is this due to issues in memory allocation? What am I missing?
I tried with malloc/free, same behaviour.

I am compiling it with:

```
g++ -o out test_thread.cpp -std=c++11 -pthread
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4
```

Thanks.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <stdlib.h>

void task(int id)
{
    int N = 10000;
    srand(100);
    int j;
    long tot = 0;

    int *v = new int[N];
/*    int *v = 0;
    v = (int *) malloc (N * sizeof(int));
    */

    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        v[j] = rand();

    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        tot += v[j];

    //free(v);
    delete [] v;
    printf("Thread #%d: total %ld\n", id, tot);
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(task, 1);
    std::thread t2(task, 2);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Comment: I would guess that `srand` and `rand` are not threadsafe. Try it with the tools from the `random` header

Comment: No, `new` and `delete` aren't thread safe per se.

Comment: @user0042 Global new and delete need to be threadsafe as per: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new#Notes

Comment: First of all instead of     rand()  just assign a value like 10     v[j] = 10;    and check whether your result are expected or not.

Comment: @Abhijit: with your suggestion it behaves as expected.

Comment: @Justin: it behaves as expected also using <random>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rand()` shares state between threads; that already accounts for your observations.